# What is the correct URL to export a config-connector config file for Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gcp-config-connector

I want to export the config-connect yaml for an existing Cloud Storage Bucket. The docs describe running `config-connector export [URL]`, however it's not clear what the URL should be for a bucket.

The [docs](https://cloud.google.com/config-connector/docs/how-to/import-export/export#exporting_example) link to https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/full-resource-names, which suggests `//storage.googleapis.com/projects/_/buckets/bucket-id`. I tried this with:

`config-connector export //storage.googleapis.com/projects/_/buckets/config-connector-experiment`

and got

```
error in 'config-connector' version '1.51.2': error getting unstructured: error getting next unstruct: error converting url '//storage.googleapis.com/projects/_/buckets/config-connector-experiment' to skeleton: error getting service mapping and resource config for url '//storage.googleapis.com/projects/_/buckets/config-connector-experiment': unable to find a matching resource config for uri path '/projects/_/buckets/config-connector-experiment'
```

The [docs](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/full-resource-names) have a footnote that says "1 The format shown here is compatible with IAM. Some services use a different format for this resource type." Perhaps there's a different format for Config Connector? If so, what is it, and can it be added to docs?

thanks!

Comment: try without the full path, in some cases, like for example when creating aggregated sinks, the Cloud Storage bucket must be referenced as a Global resource just like: storage.googleapis.com/bucket-id . 


for my example:
gcloud logging sinks create <your_sink_name> storage.googleapis.com/<target_org_bucket_name> --include-children --organization=<Source_Organization_ID> --log-filter="logName:activity"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I tried that (and added a new handful of variations) and they didn't work :(

Comment: did you try simply the `gs://bucket/path/to/file` format?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere yeah, i tried `gs://bucket`. There's no path though, by design, right?

Comment: @PaulBiggar With the intent to clarify, the correct format of the gsutil URI is: `gs://[nameOfTheBucket]/`

Comment: @nahuel yes, I was using gs://config-connector-experiment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of [June 8th, 2021](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/k8s-config-connector/issues/485#issuecomment-857169600), it's not possible as config-connector's export functionality doesn't support cloud storage.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with the bulk-export functionality (tested 9/13/22).

```bash
BUCKET='{"name":"//storage.googleapis.com/buckets/<bucket-name>","asset_type":"storage.googleapis.com/Bucket"}' 
echo $BUCKET | config-connector bulk-export
```